# MP4 Video not Playing on Github Page Website

Tags: html, html5-video, mp4

I am in the process of inserting a MP4 video (which is already converted to H.264 to make it compatible with Chrome and other websites) on a personal website based on HTML 5 using following code:

```
<video  controls >
<source src="MultiUSV_Trim_MP4.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

But what I am getting is:

[image]

The video is not working on Chrome Browser. I haven't tried to open and test my webpage on other browsers but see from other reviews that the video might work in other browsers.
I am looking for a solution which is compatible with all browsers and work with all browsers.

I tried with Firefox Browser the webpage and here is result:

[image]

Any further directions will be appreciated.

Snapshot of the media information
[image]

Comment: Are you really sure your video is actually an MP4 with H.264? Could the MP4 possibly have **h.265** video? If all fails either share a link to the video (can delete the comment later) or provide its metadata (what codec settings) which you can see using a tool like [MediaInfo](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo/Download).

Comment: @VC.One I have converted the original video to the MP4 withH.264 using VLC and have checked with VLC that the file is MP4 with H.264. Here is a snapshot of the media information in the question itself.

Comment: How are you serving the web page/video? Is your webserver set up to serve the `video/mp4` mime type? Check your network console for errors (404 etc)

Comment: @YogangSingh I suspect the _"...Converted the original video into MP4 with H.264 using VLC"_ might have done something wrong. What type of video was the original and what copy options did you use (_eg:_ direct copying of original codec)? Basically the only other way this is an actual MP4 with H.264 but not playing would be... (1) It is really a fragmented MP4 instead of normal MP4... or (2) The video has MP3 audio instead of the expected AAC audio... The final option might be to analyze the file bytes using a **hex editor** (compare your MP4 bytes to a working MP4 by following the MP4 specs)

Comment: @JonP - How are we able to do that with HTML file? I have only one index file which is the main source for the webpage hosted on Github.

Comment: @VC.One The original video was MP4 without H.264 and after conversion was MP4 with H.264. I will have to check the suggestions you provided with the Hex editor.

Comment: Please provide a link to your Github demo page if possible (can remove later). I will check it myself. Also after mentioning that you're using a 3rd party host, it's possible that the file is inaccessible like @JonP is suggesting... On Github the source cannot be like: `src="MultiUSV_Trim_MP4.mp4"` (it's longer than that)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the starting path to your page's files (so just add required filename at ending):

> https://github.com/YogangSingh/YogangSingh.github.io/raw/main/

Try as:

```
<video controls="" width="800" height="500" muted="" loop="" autoplay="">
<source src="https://github.com/YogangSingh/YogangSingh.github.io/raw/main/MultiUSV_Trim_MP4.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: @VC.one- Thanks! It sorted the Problem.

Comment: Seems not working anymore... I had to switch to the basic implementation, very annoying [![Watch the video](THUMBNAIL)](LINK)

Answer (score 0):

Your source is in same directory as your html file?

(Week ago my chrome got dizzy and i had to reset whole PC to fix exactly same issue - not loading video)

Comment: Yes same directory for Video as index.html

Comment: You can try update your browser or downgrade it.

Comment: I upgraded my browser. Same result

Comment: Did you tried close all tab's and window's then open new in incognito mode to ignore cookies, also may it be affected by an plugin if you have any installed on browser

Comment: Yes I tried to open webpage in incognito mode as well but same issue.